# how to use data of one js file in another js file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have `a.js` and qunits are written in `b.js`,input data will be present in `a.js`,so inorder to use that input data of `a.js` in `b.js`,how  can i do.i know that both js files can be included in html page.but `b.js` contains qunits for javascript methods (just like junits) these will be ran from `build.xml` so i cannot have a html Hence i cannot use html.

I tried invoking methods of `a.js` since both files are in same directory but didnt worked out.

is there any other way to use data of `a.js` in `b.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are in b.js write

```
$(document).ready({
$.ajax({
url: "",
context: document.body
}).done(function() {

});
});
```

and in this do ajax call to bring the contents of a.js and use that content on this page anywhere you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to include a Javascript file into another, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

To be briefly, there are two main methods to make it(Copy from the answer I mentioned) :

- You can load it with an Ajax call and then use eval.
- Add a script tag with the script URL in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

in a.js

```
yourGlobal = {}
yourGlobal.data = {a: 'good', b: 'c'}
```

use yourGlobal in b.js

```
if(yourGlobal) {
   function callGlobalFunction() {
        alert(yourGlobal)
   }
}
```